# Escaping period in Visual Studio Find Immediate Window

Tags: visual-studio, immediate-window

I learned about entering into the immeidate window **>of filename** trick in visual studio, but when I enter a period, which is reserved for separating menu items, it populates some junk that is irrelevant to what I want. For example, if I type **>of web.config**, and as soon as I get to the period (4th character) it would populate junk into the box.

Does anyone know how to escape it?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? What kind of "junk" gets populated in the box?  I have no problem with the period (VS 2005 & 2008).

Comment: better suited to Stack Overflow as it's about IDE usage.  migrating.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter "." without auto-complete being activated hit escape then enter ".", auto-complete will kick back in and you don't have to worry about inadvertently completing the wrong file name.